# How to message passing on chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can i send a variable from my popup.js to my content script?
For example on my popup.js

```
name = documente.getelementbyid("name")
car= documente.getelementbyid("car")
age= documente.getelementbyid("age")
```

how can i send `name`, `car` and `age`to my content script?
I don't understand how to message passing

Answer (score 0):

You need to export/import these from one file to another.

**popup.js**

```
export const name = document.getElementbyId("name");
```

**content.js**

```
import { name } from './popup';
console.log(name) //=> dom element you selected
```

Or you might, even better, create a function that will return values you want, import it and call in content file

**popup.js**

```
export const getElementX = el => document.getElementById(el);
```

**content.js**

```
import { getElement } from './popup';
const name = getElement('name')
console.log(name) //=> dom element you selected
```

Else you may modify your function to return a ready array of elements, or whatever you need.

If you are in node environment, just use [commonJS](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/) format instead of ESM presented above.

Comment: I tried but i get an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: If I remember correctly, the importing file (content.js for example), which is linked in the html file, will need to have `type="module"` (so: `<script src="content.js" type="module">`), this should help. Also, I would advise you to read about bundling files, as it has many advantages over using esm modules unbundled. Google rollup, gulp or webpack to learn more.

Comment: i need to export from the content to the popup im new to javascript

Comment: Well, in your question you wrote it the other way round... Anyway, yeah, just reverse everything I wrote and it should work. `export` statements in content.js, `import` in popup.js, and the `type="module"` on a script element calling popup.js. I'd also suggest you read up on modules, for example [here](https://javascript.info/modules-intro)

Comment: it didnt work too. I think i need to use the message passing method but i dont know how to use it